# Dual booting encrypted ubuntu 18.04 and microsoft windows

Tags: 18.04, windows, luks

Is there a way to dual boot ubuntu 18.04 with drive encryption AND windows 10? Reason being is that the ubuntu installer insists on installing encrypted ubuntu on the WHOLE DRIVE, which prevents me from making a separate partition for windows.

Normally, I would just use gparted to re-partition the drive after installation. However, luks/lvm seems to make the whole linux partition seem "full" from gparted's perspective, thus making reducing the size of the partition impossible. I tried reducing the size of the lvm partition by several guides, but none of them seem to work.

Has anyone succeeded in finding a way to dual-boot windows?

Comment: Have you read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManualFullSystemEncryption

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1773457